# QTableview: display data in specific column based on value in other column

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

I have a sqlite table containing (among other things) a "`position`" and a "`state`" field.

I want to display this table in a `QTableView` with the position as the header column and the state in the right column like this :

```
id | 1 | 2 | 3
1  | A |   |  
2  |   |   | E
```

which represents the following database entries :

```
id | position | state
1  | 1        | A
2  | 3        | E
```

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Edit : not sure if this changes anything but I need the `QTableView` to be editable too (by overriding `setData()` method of `QSqlQueryModel`)

Comment: Use QTableWidget !

Comment: You could share the database so you can take it as a test. :P

Comment: @NicolasA. QTableView is the best option for these cases.

Comment: I've updated my answer by removing the dependency of placing the indexes, now it will automatically be resolved. You could explain to me what you mean when you say it should be editable, for example the record with `id = 2, position = 2 and state = S`, as you want to edit that record.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the update. It works better ! I'll play with it and get back at you if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option for this case is to create a class that inherits from `QSqlTableModel` and modify the necessary functions as shown below:

**sqltablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef SQLTABLEMODEL_H
#define SQLTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>

class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    const QString stateName = "state";
    const QString positionName = "position";

public:
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    void setTable(const QString &tableName);
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;

   bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
private:
    int max_position;

    int index_position;
    int index_state;

    void reset();
};

#endif // SQLTABLEMODEL_H
```

**sqltablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "sqltablemodel.h"

#include <QBrush>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QTimer>


int SqlTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return QSqlTableModel::columnCount(parent)+ max_position;;
}

void SqlTableModel::setTable(const QString &tableName)
{

    QSqlTableModel::setTable(tableName);

    index_position = fieldIndex(positionName);
    index_state = fieldIndex(stateName);

    reset();
}

QVariant SqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::ForegroundRole){
        return QBrush(Qt::black);
    }
    const int number_of_columns = QSqlTableModel::columnCount();
    if(index.column()>= number_of_columns){
        if(role==Qt::DisplayRole){
            int position = QSqlTableModel::data(this->index(index.row(), index_position), Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
            if(index.column() == number_of_columns + position - 1){
                return QSqlTableModel::data(this->index(index.row(), index_state), Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
}

QVariant SqlTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole && section >= QSqlTableModel::columnCount())
        return section -  QSqlTableModel::columnCount() + 1;
    return QSqlTableModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

Qt::ItemFlags SqlTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.column() >= QSqlTableModel::columnCount()){
        return Qt::ItemIsSelectable| Qt::ItemIsEditable| Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }
    return QSqlTableModel::flags(index);
}

bool SqlTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if(role==Qt::EditRole){
        const int number_of_columns =  QSqlTableModel::columnCount();
        if(index.column() >= number_of_columns){
            bool result1 = QSqlTableModel::setData(this->index(index.row(), index_position), index.column()-number_of_columns +1, role);
            bool result2 = QSqlTableModel::setData(this->index(index.row(), index_state), value, role);

            return result1 && result2;
        }
        if(index.column() == index_position){
            QTimer::singleShot(0, this, &SqlTableModel::reset);
        }
    }

    return QSqlTableModel::setData(index, value, role);
}

void SqlTableModel::reset()
{
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec(QString("SELECT MAX(%1) FROM %2").arg(positionName).arg(tableName()));
    int val;
    while (q.next()) {
        val = q.value(0).toInt();
    }

    if(val != max_position){
        beginResetModel();
        max_position = val;
        endResetModel();
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
id |position |state
1  |1        |A
2  |2        |S
3  |1        |C
4  |4        |B
5  |3        |V
```

**Output:**

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46169378-qtableview-display-data-in-specific-column-based-on-value-in-other-column)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code : columnCount is used to draw the right amount of columns in the view, but it is also used to get the number of columns in the model which are two different things. In my case, what you call position_col, is 6 (i simplified the db for the example). When I try to get the value in this column, I get an invalid QVariant because it is superior to the max_position return by columnCount.

Comment: In any case, it seems wrong to have a mix between the column in the displayed table and the real number of columns returned by the query.